# how do I resolve pylucene installation error for java1.8 when using jcc. I am getting fata error

Tags: java-8, pylucene, jcc

I am trying to install PyLucene on my colab notebook. I am using Java 1.8 for pyLucene 8.8.1 as instructed in the documentation. Here are the steps I followed while installing it followed by the error received.

Machine details -

- Ubuntu: 20.04
- Python: 3.10
- GCC: 11.4.0

1. Installed Java 1.8 and set the path accordingly. I have mounted the drive and so will use the paths accordingly.

```
java_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/java1.8/jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java"
```

2. Installed Ant and Ivy, and set their paths

```
ant_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ant/apache-ant-1.9.16/bin/ant"
ivy_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/ivy/apache-ivy-2.5.2/ivy-2.5.2.jar"
```

3. Extracted pyLucene and set its path

```
pylucene_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/pylucene/pylucene-8.8.1/"
```

4. Installed JCC. Made one change in the setup.py file. Here is the edited part of the file. The 'linux' key is updated to reflect the pathe of JDK.

```
JDK = {
    'darwin': JAVAHOME or JAVAFRAMEWORKS,
    'ipod': '/usr/include/gcc',
    'linux': '/content/drive/MyDrive/java1.8/jdk1.8.0_202',
    'sunos5': '/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.6.0',
    'win32': JAVAHOME,
    'mingw32': JAVAHOME,
    'freebsd7': '/usr/local/diablo-jdk1.6.0'
}
```

5. Built and installed the setup.py file.
6. Edited the Makefile for PyLucene. Inserted the right paths for JDK and ANT.

```
# Linux     (Debian Jessie 64-bit, Python 3.4.2, Oracle Java 1.8                
# Be sure to also set JDK['linux'] in jcc's setup.py to the JAVA_HOME value     
# used below for ANT (and rebuild jcc after changing it).                       
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
ANT=JAVA_HOME=/content/drive/MyDrive/java1.8/jdk1.8.0_202 /content/drive/MyDrive/ant/apache-ant-1.9.16/bin/ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python3
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared
NUM_FILES=200
```

7. Now I run the `make` command, and then the `make install` command. Here is the output

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/lucene-8.8.1-py3.10-linux-x86_64.egg
Processing dependencies for lucene==8.8.1
Finished processing dependencies for lucene==8.8.1
```

8. When I run the command `make test`. That is where I get the error. Here is the error

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007a3cb50d7e3c, pid=57124, tid=0x00007a3cb88c8000
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_202-b08) (build 1.8.0_202-b08)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6d7e3c]  jni_RegisterNatives+0x7c
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /content/drive/MyDrive/pylucene/pylucene-8.8.1/core or core.57124
#
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. I have set all the paths right, but do not know where I might be wrong. Any help on this would be massively appreciated. I can share the colab notebook for further clarity.

I tried not mounting the drive and install everything in the current runtime. I change the paths accordingly in the files. However, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do the make test when the make install has been done successfully. Just run this python code to check if pylucene has been installed:

```
    import lucene
    def check_pylucene_setup():
        try:
           lucene.initVM()
           print(f"PyLucene version: {lucene.VERSION}")
        except ImportError:
            print("PyLucene is not properly installed.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    check_pylucene_setup()

    # We can check all the Lucene packages included in this distribution      of Pylucene
    print(f"Lucene packages included in this distribution of Pylucene: ")
    for p in sorted(lucene.CLASSPATH.split(':')):
        print(p)
```

It should run and as output to have:

```
    PyLucene version: 8.8.1
    Lucene packages included in this distribution of Pylucene:
    #outputs all the .jars packages you have installed with your pylucene    version
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).